# Approximate distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I'm doing some work in random graphs and there is some probability case. I have some approximation which turns out to be with density: $\mathbb{P}[X = k] = {\lambda^k \over k! }\cdot e^{-\lambda} \cdot \left( 1 + O\left( {1\over n} \right) \right)$ for some $n$. Could we find some properties of this distribution? (for example $X \sim \text{Pois}\left(\lambda \cdot \left( 1 + O\left( {1\over n} \right)\right) \right)$ or something like this? I'm not talking about some limit distribution, $1 + O\left( {1\over n} \right)$ can be read by something, close to 1.

Comment: I think you should precise your question. Your statement implies convergence in law (weak convergence of probability measure) towards the Poisson($\lambda$).

Comment: @Olivier and what if we are talking not about convergence, but about some fixed n. Are there some theorems about non-limit behaviour of such random value?

Comment: if you want to evaluate the speed of convergence you should provide us with the full model and the meaning of the $n$-parameter : probably the number of vertices/edges in your model.

Comment: This should be $X_n$ and not $X$ by the way.

Comment: @Olivier, no no, I just wanna to know, if random value with such distribution can be approximated with some poisson r.v., another that $Pois(\lambda)$.

Comment: precise your model, check the uniformity in $k$ of your $O(1/n)$, then there will perhaps be some progress.